# gnuplot takes too long to generate a 3D surface from a large dataset

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I need to make a surface plot from a large dataset. The data are laid out as a 1000x1000 gird --

```
0   0   181.59830651769676
0   1   15.378903725443536
0   2   355.2338780123731
.
.
.
999 999 108.12642321174496
```

The file size is approx. ~20MB and the command that I am trying to use is --

```
set dgrid3d 1000,1000
set hidden3d
splot 'orig-terrain.dat' with lines title 'original terrain'
```

It takes forever to generate a plot, but with a small data (100x100), I can easily get a plot like this --

[image]

How do I do this quickly for large data sets (1000x1000 grid, >20MB) ?

Comment: Whats the problem with a larger data set? BTW: There is no need for `dgrid3d` if you insert a blank line where the entry in the first column changes its value.

Comment: The question is updated, it takes too long to generate a plot, do you mean I should just say `splot 'data-file' with lines`? Sorry, I am a newbie in gnuplot.

Comment: Yes, that works if your data is formatted properly. Usually you need `dgrid3d` only for non-gridded data.

Comment: well, but if I just use `splot` the 'terrain effect' of the surface is gone. Only `splot` seems a bit faster to render, but I need to demonstrate the 'terrain effect' of the plot. I updated the image for a better understanding of my situation.

Comment: I would rather suggest to use a matrix/image format for your data, files are way smaller and quicker to display. `help image` will help you

Comment: @bibi You mean rather `help matrix` for the format. @ramgrur I guess that won't speed up the interpolation. Do you also use `set dgrid3d 1000,1000` for your larger data set? Or do you increare the sampling rate to `10000,10000`? Of course ten times more interpolation will slow down things...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Large data sets (plain text in particular) just take a long time to parse and display, in gnuplot or any other application. If you actually need all the data (i.e. plot '...' every 1000th or so point is not an option) I would suggest giving the style pm3d map a try for visualization, since at least you won't have to replot the complete thing on any tiny rotation of your result.